# elementary OS Freya not detecting partitions

Tags: system-installation, microsoft-windows

I am trying to install elementary OS 0.3.2 (Freya). However, when I try to do this, it does not detect my Windows 10 partition. I can't upload a picture, but even though I have 2 partitions in /dev/sda, it doesn't show either of them. 
If I run `sudo parted /dev/sda1 print` or `sudo parted /dev/sda2 print`, it says

```
Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/sda1: 524MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  524MB  524MB  ntfs
```

and

```
Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/sda2: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  320GB  320GB  ntfs
```

respectively. But if I run `sudo parted /dev/sda print`, it says `Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.`
All in all, I have three questions: What does this mean, why won't it detect the partitions for installation, and how do I make it detect the partitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had to reinstall windows and *then* get Elementary OS. It worked. If anyone tries this, make sure you back up your files so you don't lose anything important.